# Subset x-months ago data in r

Tags: r

I have a data from Yahoo finance and I would like to find subset only data that are within 3 months ago, then do the same for 6 months ago.  My DF is :

```
getSymbols("^IRX", from="2019-01-02")
```

The easiest solution would be to subset with -90 and -180 from today or something.

```
Df.3m <- IRX[paste(Sys.Date()-90,"::", sep="")]
Df.6m <- IRX[paste(Sys.Date()-180,"::", sep="")]
```

But the issue is that sometime 3 month has one or two days more (or less). Is there a package that find the exact date 3 month ago so i can use it to subset ?

Comment: Months are a bad unit of analysis because they're not consistent. This causes all sorts of issues especially with February. Depending on what you're doing you should consider a 30 day interval, or biweekly.

Comment: Is the interval from a specific date or relevant to the start of a period or something? Does it vary for each stock?

Comment: @Reeza, agree it is tricky, I want to dynamically calculate three-month averages and three-month stdev for example. The three months will be the same for all the stocks that this applies too, since they are all on the same market/zone

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use lubridate package to get the offsetting date:

```
library(lubridate)
dt <- Sys.Date() %m-% months(3)
Df.3m <- IRX[paste0(dt,"::")]
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up creating a quick function that seems to work :

```
Find.Date.x.month.ago <- function(current_date, x){
  Current.month <- month(current_date)
  Past.x.month <- Current.month - x
  if(Past.x.month < 0){
    Past.x.month <- 12 + Past.x.month  
  }
    trgt.day <- day(current_date)
  while (is.na(lubridate::ymd(paste(year(current_date), Past.x.month, trgt.day, sep="-"))) == TRUE) {
    trgt.day <- trgt.day - 1
  }
  return(lubridate::ymd(paste(year(current_date), Past.x.month, trgt.day, sep="-")))
}
```

Trying it with May 30th to confirm if it handle the Feb issue:

```
test.date <- "2019-05-30"
> suppressWarnings(Find.Date.x.month.ago(test.date, 3))
[1] "2019-02-28"
> suppressWarnings(Find.Date.x.month.ago(test.date, 6))
[1] "2019-11-30"
```